# Get the Height and Width of an image

Tags: haskell, repa

I'm very new to Haskell so I apologise if this is too basic, or if it makes very little sense. I'm trying to read an image; I can get it to a list of pixel data with the following code:

```hs
data Pixel = Pixel {
    red :: Integer,
    green :: Integer,
    blue :: Integer,
    alpha :: Integer
} deriving (Show)

getImagePixelArray :: FilePath -> IO (Codec.Picture.Repa.Img RGBA)
getImagePixelArray fp = do
    img <- (either error return =<< readImageRGBA fp)
    return img

getImagePixelData :: Codec.Picture.Repa.Img RGBA -> [(Word8,Word8,Word8,Word8)]
getImagePixelData img = R.toList (collapseColorChannel img)

rawPixelToPixel :: (Word8,Word8,Word8,Word8) -> Pixel
rawPixelToPixel (r, g, b, a) = Pixel  {
    red = (toInteger r),
    green = (toInteger g),
    blue = (toInteger b),
    alpha = (toInteger a)
}

main = do
    imageData <- getImagePixelArray "./images/image1.png"
    let imageRawPixels = getImagePixelData imageData
    let asPixels = Prelude.map rawPixelToPixel imageRawPixels 
    mapM print asPixels
```

I more or less follow what's going on, but my knowledge of Haskell is still limited, so when it comes to making sense of api documentation, I'm struggling a little.

I really want to be able to parse the positions of the pixels; I understand how to do that if I know the width and height of an image, **but I can't figure out how to get the width/height of an image.**

I'm making my way through a Haskell course, but I'm also trying to put it to some practical use along the way to help the concepts sink in.

Comment: Unrelated: note that the `Integer` type is meant for arbitrary precision integers -- potentially with thousands of digits. Do you really need that level of precision for the color components? If performance is an issue, that might need to be reconsidered.

Comment: @chi Ah ok, that makes sense - I don't imagine I'll _need_ to consider performance, as this is just a quick personal project, but I will consider it as it'll help me to figure things out

Answer (score 2):

Start with [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-repa-0.7.1.0/docs/Codec-Picture-Repa.html). None of what you're asking for is obviously available on `Img`, so where else could it be? There's a related `Image` type, mentioned in `convertImage`'s documentation - I wonder what that is. As it turns out, [it has a width and a height](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.2.7/docs/Codec-Picture-Types.html#t:Image). How can we get an `Image` from our `Img`, then? `imgToImage` will give us a [`DynamicImage`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.2.7/docs/Codec-Picture-Types.html#t:DynamicImage), which has several constructors each containing an `Image`. Figure out what kind of `Image` you have inside your `DynamicImage`, and then ask that `Image` its dimensions.

Perhaps there is something easier with the other lens-y stuff in that module, but it is not obvious to me, and this approach seems simple enough, if a hassle.

Comment: This is very useful, thanks; I will work my way through the parts that you mention and see what I can throw together